# Overlapping layers with different colour hues in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is apparently merged from a few pictures taken in different parts of day, but let's say I have just one photo and want to apply different hue tiers to it - how can I do it in Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to do this in Photoshop, but note that you will be missing some of the small beauties of this image, such as how the lights start to glow more and more in the darker shots.

These steps require a basic understanding of Photoshop.

1. Divide your image into ten frames, I suggest you use layer masks. I've numbered my layers 1-10 so that I can keep track as I go.

[image]

2. For mine I viewed both images at once so that I could compare as I adjusted. You can use "hue" if you wan to, but I prefer the control of using curves for something like this. Especially because it isn't just the color changing, it is the lightness/darkness as well.

[image]

3. Here is a closer view of my layers assembled. Simply apply the layer mask that you used for the photograph to the adjustment layer. You can do this by holding "alt" and dragging the layer mask to replace the other.

[image]